# select all checkbox checked all checkboxes have image in the label are not checked

Tags: javascript

I have check boxes and had a label on that and have check box image.
when i click the check box inner check box is checked and i toggle the image in the label when checked and unchecked.but when i click on select all check box browser check boxes are checked internally but my images in the label are not changed like checked.
I had tried this on

```
if(chkSelectAll)
{
    var allSelected = true;             
    for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++)
    {
        var e = document.forms[0].elements[i];
        if (e.type == 'checkbox')
        {
            var strName="";
            strName = e.name;
            if(strName.indexOf(datalist) >= 0 && !e.checked)
            {
                allSelected = false;
                break;
            }                           
        }
    }
    if(allSelected)
        currentBox.checked = true;
    else
        currentBox.checked = false;
}
```

My HTML code is

Select All

' Text='<%#GUISupport.GUIUtils.ViewEncode(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Label").ToString()) %>'
                                onclick="CheckSelectAll(this,chkSelectAllPrimaryCustomFields,'lstPrimaryCustomFields');"
                                runat="server" ID="chkPrimaryCustomFields" />

could any one help me out
thanks in advance.

I want the common code that loads whenpage get loaded

Comment: please post your html code

Comment: I don't see any jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change the labels when if condition is true?

in for loop change labels accordingly

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {

//change labels

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the labels at all in your code, please post your HTML that this script points to, so that we can give you a more detailed solution as to how to achieve this.

(this answer will be edited based on responses).

Answer (score 0):

you can following this code. 
In html code

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("admin","Admin",FormMethod.Get))
                        {
                            <input type="checkbox" name="ckbCheckAll" id="ckbCheckAll" value="" onclick="checkAll();" />
                        }
                    </th>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                i++;
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="cid" id="@i" value="@item.ID" />
                    </td>
                    <td>@i</td>
                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                </tr>
            }
</table>
```

And function checkAll() in javascript:

```
function checkAll() {
        var check = document.getElementById("ckbCheckAll").checked;
        for (var i = 1; i <= document.getElementsByName("cid").length; i++) {
            document.getElementById(i).checked = check;
        }
    }
```

Above code is working. 
Hope to help for you